# WPF - Keyboard Activity with Characters and FKeys

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF application that has a screen with some TextBoxes and I want to catch a Function Key Press (F12) and react to the contents of the TextBoxes.  What I am seeing from time to time if I type fast is that I can type a collection of characters, ABC123 for example, followed by the F12 and the function triggered by the F12 to process the TextBox contents only sees a partial string of the characters, ABC for example, in the TextBox.

The F12 key is being caught in KeyUp routine of the main window and the character input is just being handled normally based on input into a TextBox.

Any thoughts of how to make sure all input has been received before processing the press of the F12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the keys pressed are queued before being actually appended to the TextBox's Text and the F12 stroke is processed asynchronously. So at the time `F12` is pressed, only part of actual pressed characters has been appended to the Text. You can try processing the `F12` in such as `KeyUp` event handler or try creating your own buffer to store all the pressed keys and refer to that buffer instead of the `Text`'s value. I think handling the `KeyUp` is better.